# Using a User's information about which other list of Users it is following within AWS Personalize Recipe

Tags: recommendation-engine, amazon-personalize

I am using AWS Personalize to build a personalized recommender system using a social networking application's data. I had the below question:

- Is there a way to introduce the effect of following another User by a given User?
- Essentially should it have an impact on the personalized feed of a User, given the User follows a list of other Users?
- If yes, what should be the impact, in what magnitude, and how do we use this "User Following Other Users" information within Amazon Personalize.
  Thanks!